# how to customize jquery accordion pane?

Tags: jquery, html, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I want to include accordion pan in my webpage. I have implemented it successfully but now I am trying to give it some different kind of effect. What I want to do is that whichever accordion pane becomes active, that accordion pane should move on the top.

**NOTE: BOLD INDICATES ACTIVE PANE**

**PANE 1**

PANE 2

PANE 3

PANE 4

When I click on pane 3 to make it active, layout should change to something like this.

**PANE 3**

PANE 1

PANE 2

PANE 4

Can anyone tell me how can I do this?

Comment: can you plz post you have done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can just reorder elements in accordion like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/7zBcY/)

```
$('#accordeon').accordion();
$('#accordeon h3').click(function(){
   $('#accordeon').prepend($(this).next())
   $('#accordeon').prepend(this)
})
```